# How to use parameter expansion correctly in bash

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I have a string with the structure `task_name-student_name` and I want to split it into two variables:

- `task`: containing the chunk before the `-`
- `student`: containing the chunk after the `-`

I can get this to work with `sed`:

```
string="task_name-student_name"
student=$(echo "$string" | sed "s/.*-//")
task=$(echo "$string" | sed "s/-[^-]*$//")
```

However, VS Code suggests "See if you can use $(variable//search/replace) instead".

So I have two questions:

1. Why would `$(variable//search/replace)` be better
2. How do I get the parameter expansion to work without it being interpreted as a command?

When I try

```
echo $("$string"//-[^-]*$//)
```

or

```
echo $(echo $("$string"//-[^-]*$//))
```

I get this output:

```
bash: task_name-student_name//-[^-]*$//: No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: `echo "${string#*-} and ${string%-*}"` and [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: `$( )` would not  work.`${string/substring/replace}` could do simple replace but not support regex.I suggest use `IFS='-';read -a str_arr <<< "$string"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: for variable expansion, you want curly braces instead of parentheses. `$(something)` will execute `something` as a command; `${something}` will expand `something` as a variable. And just for completeness, `$((something))` will evaluate `something` as an arithmetic expression (integers only, no floating point).

As for replacing the `sed` with a variable expansion: I wouldn't use `$(variable//search/replace}` for this; there are more appropriate modifications. `${variable#pattern}` will remove the shortest possible match of `pattern` from the beginning of the variable's value, so use that with the pattern `*-` to remove through the first "-":

```
student=${string#*-}
```

Similarly, `${variable%pattern}` will remove from the *end* of the variable's value, so you can use this with the pattern `-*` to remove from the dash to the end:

```
task=${string%-*}
```

Note that the patterns used here are ["glob" expressions](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) (like filename wildcards), not regular expressions like `sed` uses; they're just different enough to be confusing. Also, the way I've written these assumes there's exactly one "-" in the string; if there's a possibility some student will have a hyphenated name or something like that, you may need to modify them.

There are lots more modifications you can do in a parameter expansion; see the [bash hacker's wiki on the subject](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). Some of these modifications will work in other shells besides bash; the `#` and `%` modifiers (and the "greedy" versions, `##` and `%%`) will work in any shell that conforms to the POSIX standard.